# Find Rcpp function in a R package

Tags: c++, r, package, rcpp

I want to print the C code of the `bh` function in the R package `frailtysurv`.
So I typed:

```
> frailtySurv:::bh
function (d_, R_star, K_, Y_, N_, N_dot, beta, theta, frailty, 
    weights, abstol, reltol, maxit) 
{
    .Call("_frailtySurv_bh", PACKAGE = "frailtySurv", 
        d_, R_star, K_, Y_, N_, N_dot, beta, theta, frailty, 
        weights, abstol, reltol, maxit)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000025263262be0>
<environment: namespace:frailtySurv>
```

With this warning at the top of the corresponding Github page:

```
# Generated by using Rcpp::compileAttributes() -> do not edit by hand
```

But then I don't find a **src** file in the 'frailtySurv' library or another file where I could find the `_frailtySurv_bh` function.
No trace of any `.Rcpp` functions in the package source.
I know that similar questions were already asked few times (example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035506/how-to-see-the-source-code-of-r-internal-or-primitive-function) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625372/r-source-code-call-function) among others) to print functions called by `.Call`.
These were not helpful in my case.

Any tip on where can I find the `_frailtySurv_bh` function?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_frailtySurv_bh` function is defined in the `RcppExports.cpp` file, which is defined [here](https://github.com/vmonaco/frailtySurv/blob/cb5e7c700218798f67305b49ce45b1be7006e41f/src/RcppExports.cpp#L354), and looks like this:

```r
RcppExport SEXP _frailtySurv_bh(SEXP d_SEXP, SEXP R_starSEXP, SEXP K_SEXP, SEXP Y_SEXP, SEXP N_SEXP, SEXP N_dotSEXP, SEXP betaSEXP, SEXP thetaSEXP, SEXP frailtySEXP, SEXP weightsSEXP, SEXP abstolSEXP, SEXP reltolSEXP, SEXP maxitSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< NumericVector >::type d_(d_SEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< List >::type R_star(R_starSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< List >::type K_(K_SEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< List >::type Y_(Y_SEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< List >::type N_(N_SEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< List >::type N_dot(N_dotSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< NumericVector >::type beta(betaSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< NumericVector >::type theta(thetaSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< String >::type frailty(frailtySEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< NumericVector >::type weights(weightsSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< double >::type abstol(abstolSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< double >::type reltol(reltolSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< int >::type maxit(maxitSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(bh(d_, R_star, K_, Y_, N_, N_dot, beta, theta, frailty, weights, abstol, reltol, maxit));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}
```

you will see it is actually a very thin wrapper for the C++ function called `bh` which is a bit too long to reproduce here, but is defined [here](https://github.com/vmonaco/frailtySurv/blob/cb5e7c700218798f67305b49ce45b1be7006e41f/src/estimators.cpp#L95).